# Maven test isn't picking up JUnit 4 Tests unless class ends with Test on a multi-module project

Tags: testing, junit, maven

> Apache Maven 3.0 (r1004208; 2010-10-04 12:50:56+0100)

running

> mvn test

ignores any JUnit 4 tests unless the name of the class is *Test.

Having just a single dependency to junit-4.8.2 and target/source configured to be 1.6

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's the standard configuration in the [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin).

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will
>   automatically include all test classes
>   with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its
>     subdirectories and all java filenames
>     that start with "Test".
> - "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its
>     subdirectories and all java filenames
>     that end with "Test".
> - "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of
>     its subdirectories and all java
>     filenames that end with "TestCase".

Source: [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) (this article also shows how you can add additional test class patterns).

Comment: The source document is actually saying otherwise (It says /Test*.java classes are included by default)

Comment: Nevermind. Though the document's saying so, actually test with latest version of the plugin proves that **/Test*.java classes aren't included.