# Why Maven is not running test cases?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am beginner in maven and I have created a maven project, when I execute  the project via clicking on as `Maven Test` it doesn't execute any test cases which is written under the `@Test` annotation.

But same code when I execute with Testng then its work fine.
Can anyone give some light to resolving it.

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Webdriver</groupId>
  <artifactId>Webdriver</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXMLFiles>
                    <suiteXMLFile>testng.xml</suiteXMLFile>
                </suiteXMLFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have test-classes in right folders? `src/test/java/...`

Comment: Xhere is testng.xml, Try <suiteXMLFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXMLFile>

Comment: @libik Yes each classes is in src/test/java/

Comment: @question_maven_com I have tried it, but its not working for me.

Comment: Just to double check: have you got the annotation as `@test` like above, or correctly as `@Test` ?

Comment: I have written @Test.

Comment: By convention, the test classes must also end with "Test". If they don't, you should add `<includes><include>**/*.java</include></includes>` to your surefire config (or something similar, this was from memory).

Comment: @user1989314 is it `org.junit.Test`?

Comment: may be already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934533/maven-test-isnt-picking-up-junit-4-tests-unless-class-ends-with-test-on-a-multi)

Comment: Show project-tree for your tests

Comment: @Slanec After adding <includes> tag it works fine. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

By convention, the test classes must also end with "Test". If they don't, you should add

```xml
<includes>
    <include>**/*.java</include>
</includes>
```

to your surefire config (or whatever includes work for you and your file naming scheme).